# Error in Ksoap2 jar file :source not found of AndroidHttpTransport

Tags: android-ksoap2

I learning android application web development. I am integrating my android application  with server using Ksoap2 jar file (ksoap2-android-assembly-2.3-jar-with-dependencies) and when I try to debug it . it shows the error "source not found "in AndroiHttpTransport.class . 
please help . thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think It is removed (Deprecated).  You can use HttpTransportSE or HttpsTransportSE instead of AndroiHttpTransport. It works fine for me.

Comment: I have tried HttpTransportSE and same error is occurring while using it

Comment: May be you can post your code here, and tell where exactly the error occur.   Did you add the ksoap2 jar to the Build Path?

Comment: yes i have added ksoap2.jar file in build path . But now i have got the solution to the problem with some once help. he asked me to add " StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);"
after setting up the content view as  It is recommended in Android  to create new thread or asynchronous task to handle any process which involves internet connectivity.... thanks for your concern and help